# событие transitionend

Tags: javascript

Есть форма и обработчик на `submit`:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var str = form.elements.text.value.toLowerCase();
     if(str != 'строка') {
        form.elements.text.value = '';
        form.elements.text.focus();
        form.classList.add('error');
        setTimeout(function(){form.classList.remove('error');}, 400);
     } else {
         location.replace('http://yandex.ru');
     }
 });
```

Суть данного кода такова: если значение инпута в момент отправки формы не соответствует некой строке, форме навешивается класс с анимацией:

```
.error {
        animation-name: error;
        animation-duration: .4s;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    @keyframes error {
        0% {left: 50%;}
        25% {left: 50.5%;}
        50% {left: 50%}
        75% {left: 49.5%}
        100% {left: 50%}

    }
```

В данный момент он удаляется с помощью таймера.

Вопрос: Как в данном случае использовать событие `transitionend`?

Если вместо `setTimeout` вешать на форму

```
form.addEventListener('transitionend', function(event) {
     form.classList.remove('error');
});
```

То оно просто не срабатывает.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас в коде анимация, поэтому нужно использовать события анимации, коими являются -

- animationstart
- animationend
- animationiteration
- animationcancel

Comment: Благодарю, думалось мне, что `transitionend` срабатывает по окончании любой CSS анимации, покрайней мере [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-transitions#%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-transitionend) так написано.....

Comment: Мне кажется что написанное относится к анимации вообще, а не конкретно к transition или animation.